# pd series from dictionary and xlsx generation with the values from the dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, xlsxwriter

I would like to generate an XLSX file with keys and values from a Dictionary. Example bellow

```
statistics = {
        "a:": f"textt",
        "b": " ",
        "c": f"{len(list_1)}",
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Statistics': pd.Series(statistics.keys()),
         'Statistics Values': pd.Series(statistics.values()))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{output_xlsx_file}", engine='xlsxwriter')

df['Statistics'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Statistics', index=False)
df['Statistics Values'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Statistics', startcol=1, index=False)
```

The expected result is to have an xlsx file with 2 columns in the col 1 dicts keys in the second column dicts values

This does happen, with one exception for the dicts values if they are a number like 3rd one in my example within the XLSX there is quote infront of the number

[image]

Any idea how can make that being a number and get rid of that quote, if I want to add in xlsx the numbers it will fail as it's not seen as a number.

Comment: because your set the len value as a string, so the output is expected. change `"c": f"{len(list_1)}"` to `"c": len(list_1)` may get what you want.

Comment: You este right. Tx